Debt collector refuses to send a bill or any info in writing to show debt is mine and it is hurting my credit report. It is not my debt. What to do?
I received a call from a debt collector asking for hospital bills.  They said they sent a bill, which they could not tell me what for, the date of service, or when they sent it.  Someone is always home (me or my adult child) and all mail is gotten by me and I have a camera which alerts when it comes so I know no one else takes it.
They called harassingly daily for 2+ years, on average 5-8 times per day between 6 am past 8pm.  No company I know calls people that early or late.  After months of asking for the above info, they gave a date of service and I informed them it was not possible it was my debt because I was not in that neighboring state for months before or after that time and I could prove it.  They said they would send a copy of the bill to my email but the link they sent did not work.  I requested to receive it in writing by email, fax, and many times by postal mail, anything to validate the debts, and have gotten nothing.
3 years later, the debt is still killing my credit!  I have reported to the credit bureaus my issue, that the bills are not mine and could not possibly be because I was not in the state or at that hospital and they remain still.  I have never gotten any itemized bill, document with my signature on it for the services they say are what the debt is from, or any evidence it is my debt.  They don't call all the time anymore but they still regularly call.  I have spoken to "supervisors" and they just tell me this debt is yours and you need to pay it.  I have told them that according to the law they need to produce the bill and validate the debt but several times they threatened me with a lawsuit if I don't pay and hung up when I ask for this.  I have told them I have submitted evidence that proves I could not be the debt owner and asked for it removed from credit reporting and they refuse.  They claim they have sent bills but I have only gotten 3 make a payment statements.  They won't show validation of the debt.  I called the actual hospital and they say I was a patient and they forward it to the collector but I was not there or in the state.  I was in appointments that day performing procedure services which require me to log every client's ID and complete state required reporting paperwork we both sign.  This should be enough to exhonorate me that I was spending all day in another state but the collector doesn't accept that.  Again, I was not in the neighboring state 30 days before or after this and not at this hospital.  I submitted proof with the DL and name of the clients blocked out for their privacy to prove it was not possible it is my debt.  They are doing nothing but still asking for money and report of unpaid bills is dragging my credit down.  I want it fixed.  What should I do?   I did a free consult with an attorney and they said to take me on they wanted 5k retainer which I can't afford just to remove this from credit reports.

You said "the collections is killing my credit".  How so?  How low is your score?  How much higher do expect it to be?  What is it preventing you from doing?

https://www.kalzumeus.com/2017/09/09/identity-theft-credit-reports/

To summarize, you have talked to them on the phone and given them multiple ways to provide a verification of debt, which they have not done. They are required by law to provide this letter. The only problem is the length of time this debt has existed. At this point both the credit agencies and the collector will assume the debt is legitimate.
You need to send a dispute letter via certified USPS mail and pay extra for the return receipt so you know they received it. In the letter, state that they must send a verification of debt to your home address within 30 days. I'm sure you can find examples of how to word the letter online.
Going off of FTC rules, with the frequency of calls you describe, they have already broken several laws. Report the agency to:

Your state's attorney general's office
The Consumer Federal Protection Bureau (CFPB)

The FTC has a helpful FAQ page on this topic.
The results of the certified letter and AG/CFPB complaints should give you plenty of info to provide to the credit agencies and get the debt taken off your report.

no, i don't  think you should send them anything at this point! that will provide them more information about you  in pursuing false debt collection. you aren't disputing a debt with someone you did business with, you are being falsely billed  with false info,by some unrelated unknown  third party   scamming you,  it sounds like. . There is a difference.
There are attorneys who can advise you as to a process, sometimes for free. They might want to  take your case on contingency and make the scammers pay instead of you.
You should report this scam to the authorities, ie FTC website, and  Consumer Affairs of your State Attorney General, etc. also you can probably get an attorney to ding the  harassers for several  law violations and pay you by court ordered garnishment eventually.
The  Credit Bureaus also are at fault, if you have gone thru t he process of   removing false  debts that don't belong to you. If you haven't, then go to the Bureaus' websites and  find the link for  reporting and removing. If they don't, then you can also file a  court case against them. They aren't allowed to keep reported and provably false debts on their systems and could  win you some  penalty money against them, especially when it is  altering your credit scores ie, damages.

FTC in general has no enforcement power, they will take your complaint and if it adds to others and the amount is high enough, they might refer it to the justice department. Otherwise, they just take complaint and your credit is still being trashed. The only way in these cases is to take them to small claims court, unless you have the funds to hire a lawyer and force them to show evidence in court, at which time you can ask for punitive damages in addition to whatever you can show their damage to your credit actually cost you. Waiting idle in the hopes that a complaint will make you whole?
